# Downvote answers to questions that should be closed?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, vote-to-close, deleted-questions

A [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188362/what-does-mean-in-ruby-is-it-a-block-mixed-with-a-symbol) was a common duplicate. (16 duplicate questions were posted in the comments!)

Based on my experience that it's hard to get a question deleted when it has answers (especially upvoted ones) I downvoted the existing answers to:

1. Encourage the authors to delete them.
2. Encourage the authors to search for duplicates before answering a FAQ.
3. Ease the path to question deletion.

Should my behavior be considered beneficial to SO (dampening noise) and encouraged, or considered harmful (discouraging answers) and discouraged?

Comment: [These](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50358) [questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93296) [are](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55848) [probably](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466) [relevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451).

Comment: @RobHruska Kinda ironic, eh? hehe... I wonder if Adam and I should be down voted for answering this question... `</tongueInCheek>`

Comment: I know sympathy votes are frowned upon, but in this case I upvoted that answer to counter your -1 :)

Comment: Most amusing, @Rob :)

Comment: @Bart Oh noes! :)

Comment: @Phrogz - Indeed. Really, though, when it comes to meta, pretty much everything's a duplicate of everything else.

Comment: I downvote answers to duplicate questions if the answerer has the rep for a VTC and I know they know better.   A lot of these will get answered because it's easy rep-farming.

Answer (score 14):

I really wish people wouldn't lose their minds over duplicates.  Why is it so important to you that a dup get **deleted**?  Having multiple duplicate questions, likely with slightly different titles, provides more paths for Google to shuttle people to Stack Overflow.  That's a good thing.

So no, I certainly would not downvote good answers to questions that have been asked before.

Comment: I agree; The reason for the automatically generated link to the original is to help with that; and the existence of those differently-worded duplicates actually helps for those who pay attention to the "Related" list that pops up while typing a question. I also note the "merge" feature in my answer, as something that expects good answers will also be left on dupes.

Comment: @Andrew - for sure.  Exact duplicates for trivial questions will be merged, as they should be.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion; it is important to me that we not _proliferate_ or _encourage_ duplicates.

Comment: @Phrogz I would agree with that, but we have to settle on a *reasonable* way to accomplish that. For instance, we do not have an "expert review" process where questions are not posted publicly until someone certifies that it is not a duplicate - even though that would reduce dupes significantly. We also need to balance it with usability and approachability. I think it is for those goals that the current close-vote system was designed.

Answer (score 6):

Ultimately, your legitimately-registered votes need not answer to anyone but yourself. If you believe that an answer to a frequent duplicate is "Not helpful", then down voting would seem to meet the spirit of that feature's intent.

Two things come to mind, though;

First, the votes probably won't have the effect you want without doing what you did on the question you link: Commenting why you down voted. But I'm not convinced such a comment/down vote will accomplish your goal. In the case of some folks, it may encourage them to do the exact opposite.

Second, questions that are duplicates are eligible to be *merged*, for the situation where a duplicate receives good answers and the 'original' question seems canonical enough. So, the system was designed for this to happen.

---

I don't think I would do this, myself. Duplicates will happen, and people posting answers won't always have any clue a duplicate existed. Often, a duplicate might get a *better* answer than the 'original' ever did - which I expect is why the 'merge' option exists for mods.

I would simply mark the post as a duplicate, and leave it at that. Don't up vote any of the answers.

Comment: *But I'm not convinced such a comment/down vote will accomplish your goal. In the case of some folks, it may encourage them to do the exact opposite.* - I could actually see it resulting in a *net gain* in reputation to the answerer, with some people applying a "counter/sympathy-upvote", since the answer's probably a correct and helpful one.