# What should be done with dupe-question-accepted-answer-linkers?

Tags: discussion, reputation, duplicate-questions

In some dupe question cases, users may link to the correct answer from the dupe question and gain rep from this.

[Here's an example that makes my teeth itch.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476673/css-justify-text-fill-space-with-dots/5476837#5476837)

Rather than flag as dupe, or vote to close as dupe, he links to the correct answer from the duplicated question and gets 35 reputation points (at this time).

I closed as dupe and deleted the answer... but undeleted it.  I'm not sure what the appropriate thing to do here is.  Perhaps I'll just go look at Skeet's profile and ponder the futility of it all...

Comment: However in this particular instance it is not a user who could have potentially closevoted (or even knows about the process). And I'm not sure it should go unrewarded when people manage to find a duplicate (not overly obvious one in this case).

Comment: @mario: I don't care, he still should be smitten.  Smited?  Smite-ed?  Aw, hell, I'll just ban him.

Comment: @mario It doesn't take any rep to flag as a duplicate and let a mod handle it. As for gaining rep for finding the duplicate, that's been [discussed at great lengths with no real consensus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions).

Comment: @marcog: That's one of the discusions I had in mind, and I realize it's a broad topic, mostly cons for everyone involved. Back to this case: while the user was unaware of quite a lot, he simply copied over the answer from someone else. I would consider that the real offense here, rather than the dupe or link-as-answer issue.

Comment: @mario: Da bastid didn't even have the common courtesy of hiding the fact that he stole the answer!  He linked back to the source!  It makes our jobs very hard when people are honest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I must admit to being a bit brutal here; my approach is "convert to comment" (which has an automatic delete) and "close -> duplicate"

Comment: I like this one, gonna try it on for size.

Comment: Mmm, feels good against the skin.  I'll take it.

Answer (score 3):

I say delete it as "Not an answer".

If it's a duplicate question, it's likely to be merged anyway. When merged, the question will have an answer plus an answer that links to the first. That's in no way helpful.

Answer (score 1):

An equally heinous fault with that answer is that it doesn't actually give the answer, it just gives a link to some other website. What if jsfiddle goes away? The answer is completely useless then.

Answer (score -2):

Is it really that bad? People get 'points' for less useful posts. Just close the question.

Comment: The more users see these "answers" on other questions, the more likely they are to follow suit instead of closing as duplicate. So yes, it really is that bad.