# Why do closed questions still give reputation to the asker?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, closed-questions

I'm sorry if I'm asking something that doesn't belong here, but:

Why are questions that are closed, still able to be up/down voted? This is quite disruptive to the quality of the scoring. As far as I've seen inappropriate questions are closed in a pretty fair way, yet some of them keep being voted A LOT thus giving the guy who asked them a ton of reputation for no good reason.

I've actually seen people who (intentionally or not) ask some flame/trolly question that gets A LOT of attention, gets a bunch of votes, then is closed but the votes keep coming in. They're users who have like 300+ reputation solely from posting closed questions. They never asked a useful question, never contributed with an answer to someone else's question.

So again, should a question, once is deemed "Closed" revoke the reputation points that it added to the asker, and also no longer be able to be voted?

Comment: "Report" such questions here and if they're really not helpful, we got enough 10K+ users here to delete them..

Comment: See the other side: If closed question cannot be voted, nobody could down-vote them too.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: right, I'll try to do that.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: well, yes, but once the question is closed there wouldn't be any need to be downvoted any longer, I was questioning why those questions are still votable AFTER being closed. At any rate, seems there was something I was missing (as per the answer below), so my point is kindda moot now.

Comment: OK, don't forget to notify when you edit, as it won't send any notification of its own. (the editing of your question)

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions that discusses this type of thing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a question is closed it still has the chance of being reopened, so it should still be able to be voted on normally.  If it really doesn't deserve to be on the site (a point that's contentious, I know) it will eventually be deleted.  After a reputation recalc a user will lose any reputation points gained from deleted posts.

Comment: Oh didn't notice that, sorry. So in fact if a closed question stays closed (and unmodified) for too long it will be actually removed and those reputation points will no longer be present for the asker. That's not too bad. And I understand why this is so, so that the asker  will still have the chance to fix his question. Thanx for pointing this out.

Comment: Actually only question with no upvotes will be automatically removed by the system. Having upvotes will cause that it can be deleted only manually, either by three 10K+ members or by a moderator.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the comments, that actually what I was looking to find out. And just so you all know, I did read the FAQ, but  I guess I missied these infos (or didn't get them from the general context),

Comment: Why can't voting still be enabled, without giving anyone possitive rep unless the quesions is reopenned?  (I don't see why the two sites must be tied together)