# Why am I still losing reputation points on a questions that was already closed?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do closed questions still give score points to the asker?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113208/why-do-closed-questions-still-give-score-points-to-the-asker)

I asked a question ["How to combine 4 jquery functions into one"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979219/i-need-to-combine-4-jquery-functions-into-one-function-that-will-be-applied-to-a). I explained that I am able to do these functions individually but I am looking for a way to combine them. One person understood and tried to answer. The question have then being voted down, I lost 12 reputation points on it. The question was then closed. After which I lost an additional 2 points. I believe that my question was fair enough that it should not have lost any points.

Comment: Your question doesn't show any prior effort, and that's what usually downvotes are for.

Comment: Don't let it get to you, some people just love to down vote for the sake of down voting and piling on.  Some even think it's funny to pile on.  Nothing you can do about it.  I do feel your pain, though.  Hang in there.

Comment: @ChrisGerken With this kind of de-motivation it is making me think twice about asking for help. I mean I found this website because I research on google what I wanted to do and this site always had the answers that worked. So I decided to join and ask the pros directly. I always research my question but with google the answer is only as important as the question you ask.

Comment: @Bryan: Your newly edited question is much better than the original. One consideration is that you said "I know how to do each one," but you didn't provide the code for each, which is asking SO to rewrite a lot of code you already have.

Comment: Yup, the trick on asking questions, though, is to narrow the scope as much as possible.  If you know how to solve 95% of the problem then keep that part out of the question. The greater the scope the more likely the question will be misinterpreted as a "gimme the codez" question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A closed question is still active to a certain extent. It can still get comments, it can still be edited (and improved) and it can still get voted to be re-opened. A question being closed is far from the end of it's road.

There are some problems with your question though. Possibly the main problem is that you have failed to show an attempt to solve it. Posting some code of what you have tried (even if it doesn't work), shows that you have put some effort and thought behind the post.

---

Another theory is that people are seeing that list of functions you want to do and immediately think that you are requesting an entire complete (and documented) script. Perhaps mentioning that the problem is combining the commands together at the start of the post would help minimize this.

Comment: hhhmmm the list was there and I did mention that I wanted to combine the functions. I also stated that I can work the functions individually however I did not provide an example of what I have and what I have tried. So if I revised the question and add scripts that have being tried or where I am stuck would help in re-opening this question?

Comment: It would certainly help (no guarantees, though).

Comment: Most certainly! It's a step in the right direction.

Comment: @Lix I already added some codes that I was trying and revised my original question. By the time I was finish 5 reputation points was added back and I don't know why?

Comment: @Bryan- someone has upvoted your question.

Comment: @Lix - Your sunglasses look very nice..... :D