# Is downvoting a question that has been closed by the moderators allowed?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, closed-questions

One of my questions on stats.stackexchange had been closed. Two users have downvoted it and the score has been reduced by 4. I would like to see the rule. If it is there.

Comment: Edit your question on stats.SE and add more info, be very careful not to change your question, and when adding more info please consider the current answer and don't make that answer obsolete. Then your question will potentially be re-opened, and perhaps gain some upvotes - or at least removal of some of the downvotes if downvote users re-visit :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been discussed before, such as [Why am I still losing reputation points on a questions that was already closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159785/289879) and [Why do closed questions still give reputation to the asker?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113208/289879).  But the gist of it is, yes it is allowed to downvote a closed question, just as it is okay to upvote an improved closed question.

Consider:

1. [Members can vote as they please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/165773)
2. If the members find the post does not meet the standards, they are free to downvote as an indication that the post is *still* not up to standards.

If the question has been closed due to being off topic, then it should not be discussed (Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum).

Finally, don't stress about -4 fake internet points.

Comment: I can not understand the term fake internet points.

Comment: @subhashc.davar "Fake internet points" is a term meaning the reputation you earn on Stack Exchange sites is just a number on the internet. It has no real relevance to life away from the internet, in fact not even anywhere on the internet away from Stack Exchange sites. So other than for privileges etc on Stack Exchange, the rep is meaningless - do not worry about losing them, especially losing only "4". We lose rep, it's how the site works, just don't stress over it.

Comment: @James thanks for the clarification and motivational support.