# Why was this downvoted and marked as localized?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have a perfectly good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603838/strange-border-in-login-form-after-compiling) and it was downvoted. This could easily happen to the next person who comes here, because I was not aware that normalize.css was being used on CodePen. Further more, it was downvoted, with those 2 combined, I'm question banned. I'm sorry for ranting, but I think this was improperly closed.

Comment: It might have been downvoted because of your snarky comment...  Just sayin.

Comment: And it actually is just 1 lousy downvote.

Comment: @seth :) didn't mean it as snarky.

Comment: @juergend Well, this one got me question banned.

Comment: "it looks weird" doesn't help it apply to more than just your own situation

Comment: If you don't want people to take it as snarky I recommend staying away from risky sarcasm like that..

Comment: @Seth Sorry, D:

Comment: @random I had a clear screenshot of what was wrong on the post.

Comment: What does someone else search for to make your question helpful to them? Work on that and it helps take away the "too localised" part

Comment: This has [happened before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170457/206222) to you; I suggest looking over some upvoted questions to see what people are looking for.

Comment: @random ex. Code looks great in CodePen but wonky in browser

Comment: Too localized is all but deprecated - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168778/183887

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your question has been reopened.  I took the liberty of adding the solution that you reported that solved your problem as a Community Wiki answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Did you delete my 2 comments as well?

Comment: Yes. . . . . . . . .