# Code conversion when the target language doesn't have the "feature"

Tags: discussion, questions

While reading [What should be the close reason for "convert / translate my code" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175705/what-should-be-the-close-reason-for-convert-translate-my-code-questions) I was curious towards my [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368697/vb-net-to-c-sharp-conversion-with-the-treeview-in-wpf) about a VB.NET WinForms to C# WPF conversion project.

VB.NET features late binding allowing you to call `.Name` on a `TreeView.Nodes(int)`. As C# doesn't feature late binding, `TreeView.Items[int]` returns an `object`. Perplexed on what to do, I asked here on StackOverflow.

Is my question valid or should it have been closed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why you even ask yourself whether it should have been closed. It's definitely not a typical "Translate my code" type question. Those look like this:

```
Hi, I need to translate this code into x language.

(wall of code)
```

Comment: It wasn't closed. I'm asking if it should have.

Comment: @Cole nope, it shouldn't have. It looks like a totally legit question to me. You're not asking for anyone to do your job, you're showing own effort and research, etc.

Comment: It's not a bad question.