# What should be the close reason for language conversion questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, close-reasons

We already have a question like this [What should be the close reason for “convert / translate my code” questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175705/216721) but all the answers there are obsolete now, as the *close reasons* for questions have been completely changed since it was answered.

So, with the new reasons in place, which *off-topic* reason should be given for a questions which ask for language conversion? That's because the question might fit more than one reasons in the *off-topic* category. For example, this question [Convert simple java code to c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20064113/2024761) neither *demonstrates a minimal understanding of the problem* nor *describes a specific problem by producing a valid code* attempt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think *too broad* better serves the worst of these; a wall of code with a note stating what language they'd like is an assignment, not a question, no matter how many times they abbreviate the word please. Likewise, we can't be expected to compare and contrast the same class in two languages in hopes of documenting what's wrong.

When you get to questions that give a reference implementation from a language that they know which *isn't* a giant wall of code, and some attempt - however meager - in the target language, then I think you have an answerable question. I can't say that as a blanket statement, because context is king in these situations.

If it's *painfully* obvious that the person has not put more than ten minutes into actually attempting to learn the fundamentals of the target language, then *minimal understanding* comes into play - they need to know basic types and syntax in order to be *stuck*, prior to that they're simply *tasked*.

Describing a specific problem is sometimes *exactly* what they need help doing in these cases, at least partially, especially if they're unwittingly looking at a round hole with a square peg. Just judge each question individually. Are they looking at lists in a new language coming from arrays in another? That can be *really* confusing, and extremely difficult to articulate.

A modicum of effort isn't too difficult to detect, and that's what sets the better variety of these apart from the sludge.

Comment: I'm answering more generally here, a bit outside of the types noted in the question, since we see these in so many forms.

Comment: Actually I was expecting a general answer only(restricting to code conversion questions though), because the SO question I linked was just an example to show that questions might fall under various categories. My question wasn't to know, how to handle the linked question alone, making your answer, the most suited one for this post(atleast for now).

Answer (score 2):

The close reason used on that question seems reasonable.  Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

However, do note that the question isn't actually a code conversion question.  The op's question is more specific than that; he wants to know *how to create the array in C# without knowing ahead of time how many elements are in it.*

Comment: It is specific, but I still feel its a conversion question, because though the OP wants to create an array without knowing the array of elements, this sentence *How do I write this in C#*, IMHO, is a giveaway.

Comment: @R.J not really. if the question is specifically about how to create an array in C#, it is an appropriate question on SO (assuming it isn't a duplicate). You may stil feel the question does not show enough effort, but that doesn't neccessarily mean the question should be closed - the answers may still be very useful for future readers.

Comment: @JanDvorak - In that case, there are several questions being closed day-in and day-out for this very reason, that there is no effort shown by the OP. How do we handle them?

Comment: @R.J I'd rather say: first decide _if_ the question should be closed (does it make SO a better place for googlers, or  a worse place?), _then_ decide what is the best close _reason_.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Fair enough. Point taken! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd usually use the “minimal understanding” one:

> Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding** of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

I don't think the “describe a specific problem one” fits:

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

This latter one says problems *with code you've written*. In most of the code translation questions, it's not obvious that they *have* written the code in the target language. Until then, it fits the first and only the first reason: that they must have some minimal understanding of how to do it in the target language.

Of course, once they've produced some candidate translation, even if it doesn't work, that alone might make it a valid question, or at least make it fall under some other category, because at that point, it's not a question of how to translate it, but what's wrong with the translation.

Comment: Reading your explanation, I feel that the second scenario might never pop-up at all. I agree that the OP show a minimal understanding of the problem, but in this case, the OP knows what the problem at hand is, but just that the OP has made no effort, and thus, it should fall under the describer a specific problem with a valid code to demonstrate it right?

Comment: @R.J: In the question you gave, they showed the code they used in Java. They did not show their attempted translation to C#. Since they didn't show what they tried, it was assumed that they didn't, and so should be closed as “requires minimal understanding”. Had they given the code they wrote in C# (say, using the length), they could then have asked if there was a way to write it without accessing length directly, and then they'd have a pretty decent question that, while basic, shouldn't be closed at all.

Comment: @R.J: I think the only case in which the latter close reason (“must describe specific problem”) would be appropriate is if they explicitly said they did try it but only said “it didn't work,” without describing the problem further. In that case, (possibly after a close vote) they should be prodded into showing exactly *what* they tried and exactly *what* isn't working.

Comment: Your second reply fares well in comparison to the first, though I feel that not always, when a code is not produced, that it should be closed with the minimal understanding reason. It depends a lot on the context as well.