# Award accepted answer reputation for finding duplicates verified by OP

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, fastest-gun

Consider the following theoretical situation:

New user asks a question:

> Why does my program process a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?

I see this question, I can:

1. Vote to close as duplicate
2. Answer the question with a [link to the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/1768232), with possibly a little bit of extra explanation to their exact scenario

In the first case, I get rewarded with nothing.

In the second case, I will probably get an accepted checkmark and 15 rep ([if I am FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/200235)), and the asker will get two rep for accepting my answer. **We are both encouraged to leave this duplicate open!**

#### Therefore, I propose that we make the rewards for these two scenarios equal.

Now that we [have a new user interface that allows people to close their own questions as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/200235), we should have the user verifying that their question is a duplicate provide the exact same rep as if they had *accepted an answer that said the same thing.*

Some caveats:

1. <strike>To prevent people from posting duplicate questions on purpose to gain rep, we would not award the +2 for an accept, just the +15 accepted answer rep to the duplicate finder.</strike>

   - It seems the consensus in the answers is that giving this +2 rep is not only okay, but preferred. FWIW I am okay with this.
2. We would only award the +15 rep if the **asker themselves** clicks the "that solved my problem!" button. If it's closed as duplicate from 5 CVs, then *no rep would be assigned.*

   - This basically means that the person marking it as a duplicate is now encouraged to explain why the duplicate question is a duplicate in the comments, because they must get the asker to believe their question is now answered. In my opinion, this is a good thing.
   - **This is a core part of this proposal. If this were not part of it, I wouldn't support the idea myself.**
   - This piece of the proposal is also why this question is not, itself, a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions?rq=1) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164620/reputation-for-finding-an-exact-duplicate?rq=1) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5?rq=1).

Comment: Related: [Are there any studies on the techniques used to find duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260898/are-there-any-studies-on-the-techniques-used-to-find-duplicates) Also undownvoted. We really need more information.

Comment: I gotta say, I like this idea. Needs a bit of debate, but seems far less awkward than most of the previous suggestions.

Comment: How would this tie in with gold badge closures?  For the tags I have a gold badge in, my choices are to instaclose or leave a comment saying that I think it is a duplicate.  For newer users that don't understand the rules, they'll often visit the linked question and copy/paste it as an answer to their own question.

Comment: @cimmanon per my reading award goes only to those who voted (and flagged?), commenters get nothing (otherwise people would start abusing it by posting dozens comments pointing to different questions in hope to guess one right). I think this means dupehammers are outta this game. Can't tell if this is fair or not, although given that gold badge indicates expectation that finding dupes is easier than for other users (based on profound knowledge of the tag) I am rather inclined to consider this okay

Comment: It isn't fully clear if you want the "duplicate solves my problem" flag replaces the accepted answer flag.  I'm assuming so, since this (usually) moves the incentive for the answerer from "answer duplicate - gain rep" to "mark as duplicate, likely gain more rep".

Comment: consider [edit]ing to account for the case if question gets reopened. For duplicates closed by asker this is likely a minor corner case but still...

Comment: @gnat Consider proposing what should be done in that situation in your own answer

Comment: I would do but couldn't figure it. You see, this is rather weird case - asker says it's a dupe, it solved my problem - and... five 3K users suddenly pop up outta thin air and say no it's not ("it doesn't really solve your problem"???). Having difficulty imagining how to handle this :)

Comment: @gnat Choosing community duplicate could lock the question in the same way migrated questions get locked. But I'm just spitballing I agree with you it's a pretty weird case

Comment: hm locking could solve this, yes - but it could add a different issue - question would become harder to maintain. No edits, no retags? not good - given how unlikely is the case we try to address, it feels like killing gnats with a cannon. Lock would apply to _all_ self-closed dupes, while probability of reopening these may be around 0.01%

Comment: We don't allow anyone to override the OP's choice of normal accepted answers, @gnat; just let the dupe finder keep the rep unless and until the asker accepts another answer/duplicate.

Comment: @JoshCaswell that's fantastic, thanks! this reasoning really makes it clear how system should behave (implementing it technically may be not quite as straightforward as we handle regular accepts but that's secondary). Since you did it so well, :) mind trying to crack yet another nut - how could dupehammers integrate in this picture?

Comment: ...oh and I think I figured "straightforward" technical implementation for this corner case. System should just automatically raise mod attention flag when such a reopen happens (["DisputedCommunityDuplicate"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299376/839601 "like it does for questionable LQ deletions: 'DisputedLowQuality'")). Since we expect this to be rare, _exceptional_ case, resolving it sounds just the kind of job for moderators. @durron597 consider [edit]ing this in if this reasoning makes sense

Comment: That's a harder one, @gnat, but if the "stub answer" is included in the way this is implemented, then that would probably be the way for the OP to approve the hammer action.

Comment: What's your take on people using [duplicate-finding bots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261172/present-and-future-of-bots-on-stack-exchange)?

Comment: @DeerHunter This question is beyond the scope of this MSE question. If you'd like to chat about it, you can find me in the [SO Close Vote Reviewers chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Answer (score 28):

I'm in agreement with [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260893/award-accepted-answer-reputation-for-finding-duplicates/260902#comment850685_260893) that this seems like a reasonable suggestion. Duplicate questions bug me... a lot, so much that during my interviews with SE it was one of the things I raised as something I'd like to see fixed or improved.  I'm putting some thoughts into an answer to get some feedback and maybe flesh this idea out a bit more.

Your proposal is very close to something I have been kicking around for a little while now. The things I like about it are:

- it rewards users to find duplicates
- we can potentially still give something the user who asked the duplicate question (with the +2 accept), many times these are new users who are trying to contribute to the site and gain some rep - if they accept the other question is the solution, then I think rewarding them with something is good
- we'll have more signposts to the best question and answers

I also think there is an additional side effect that may result from this, in that, it might alleviate some of the frustration users feel when people answer duplicates. Minimizing even a little frustration is a good thing... right?

I do see a few potential problems that need to be hammered out on this.

- What happens if the question gets re-opened? Does the user who benefited from the original duping of the question lose the rep?  I'd say yes to minimize gaming on something like this.
- Does the OP who asked the question also lose the rep awarded for validating the dup if it gets reopened?
- How will this work with gold-badge holders? We still want them to close obvious duplicates but there will not be a UI that is created for the OP to accept it due to the single vote.  Excluding a large group of users with significant knowledge in a tag seems detrimental and *might* result in gold-badge holders answering questions instead of closing. Maybe, they get some reputation if the question doesn't get reopened after a certain number of days... not sure yet though.

I'm worried about potential abuse that I haven't yet thought of but I'm going to chew on this a bit more.  I'd really like to see something implemented to better handle the duplicate question problem.  I am going to [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) this because it's high time we do something about this.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent input! [My stub answer idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260902/200235) addresses the "what if it gets reopened" problem, because then everything gets treated within the regular system. As far as gold badge holders, I've been thinking about this all day... I don't think it matters too much if their incentives are wrong because they already have so much rep to have gotten a gold badge (I have 13k in basically one tag and I still don't have a gold badge) they probably won't care. And there just aren't that many of them.

Comment: @durron597 I also like the stub answer idea. I really like this proposal it's really similar to what I've been trying to work out in my head.  There are still a few kinks that need to be figured out and I need to think a bit more on how to prevent gaming but I'm hoping this would be turned into something.

Comment: As part of the review, it might be useful to have stats as to how often an asker actually participates in a duplicate closure. My gut tells me this will only be a small fraction of duplicate closures, as these closures either happen by the community before the asker has come back (particularly with gold badge closures) or the asker tends to be upset with having their question be closed. Even if this proposal is put in place, I wonder how many questions will be impacted by it.

Comment: @BradLarson you need to account for that additional incentives will likely increase amount of dupe votes / flags. Users currently motivated to only answer will get an option to gain from proposing dupes. Who knows how many jump that train. Current stats can't tell us

Comment: Roughly 15% of the duplicates closed in the past 30 days (1186 posts) were triggered by asker confirmation, @Brad. Not gonna change the world, but not peanuts. Worth making a prominent part of a slightly more elaborate plan, I'd say.

Comment: @Shog9 - That does seem worth it, then, particularly if incentives promote more of this behavior. Thought the numbers would be much lower than that.

Comment: @Shog9 Are those 1186 posts network-wide or just Stack Overflow?

Comment: That's just SO @durron - I'm much too lazy to add this up network-wide.

Comment: Is the "Shog9" link supposed to go to some super secret room that the rest of us can't view? I'm also curious how this would affect gold-hammer holders, as it's not like they stop caring about reputation after they get their hammer.

Comment: No idea where that link came from, @Kevin - I've replaced it with perhaps a more likely target. As for gold-badge closers, I believe this could be made to work for them as well.

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest that the asker still be given +2 rep for saying that finding a duplicate solved their problem.  Though there would be an incentive to ask duplicate questions for the sake of 2 rep, this is only slightly worse than the current situation, where you can intentionally ask a duplicate and hope to get at least one answer before it's closed. Either way a user risks downvotes and/or question bans by doing this.

If you *don't* award the +2 rep, the asker has an incentive to accept an answer rather than agreeing that a helpful duplicate has been found.

Giving the +2 seems like a good tradeoff, since it creates a minor and hazardous way of gaming the system but helps close an effective and pernicious way of gaming the system - answering known duplicates before they get closed.  It also helps duplicates get found faster and cuts down on the burden of cleaning up sites.

Comment: Come to think of it, all that would have to happen is one person notice the duplicate gaming the system and one downvote would negate the +2.

Comment: Maybe make the +2 a +1 if its closed as duplicate to encourage non dupe question asking?

Answer (score 5):

This is a follow-up idea that is *not an essential portion of the first idea*. Therefore, I am adding it as an answer so that it can be voted on separately.

When an asker selects "That solves my problem!" it could create **a stub answer with a checkmark,** exactly as if the person who found the duplicate had written it as an answer.

This would accomplish two things:

1. It would be even more clear to future readers that this duplicate solved the asker's problem.
2. It would allow the asker to remove the checkmark if they change their mind and decide that their question is not a duplicate.

   - This would not reopen the question, they would need to get 5 reopen votes to do this.

Unfortunately, a side effect of doing this is that it would be awkward not to assign the +2 rep for accepting an answer. The only solution I can think of is flagging "creating duplicates on purpose" for moderator attention; I think it would not be that hard to if people began to create duplicates on purpose just for the +2 rep. This rep could, potentially, also be capped in the same way that rep is capped for suggesting edits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create CW answer for every “Vote to close as duplicate” vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198958/165773) :)

Comment: @gnat It's not a duplicate of that because this answer wouldn't be CW (because you CAN get 15 rep from it). I suppose you could get more than 15 rep actually, if people upvote the stub.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Comment: @gnat http://stackoverflow.com/q/28504747/1768232

Comment: the one at SO matches [Section 1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773); one here seems to be more like covered in section 2 "only looks similar..." :)

Comment: I like this a lot. It goes some way toward addressing the primary concern over the proposal that gnat cited, which is a link-only answer that encourages *other* link-only answers - once the question is closed, no more answers can be posted. I have no real concerns about awarding +2 to the asker; if you exclusively post duplicates, you'll be q-banned before you can garner any real reputation that way.

Comment: Often, more than one user casts a duplicate vote before the OP accepts it's a duplicate. Who owns the answer? Who gets the rep? I guess only the first one, who did the hard work of finding the duplicate. Makes sense...

Comment: This *really* gets fun when you have multiple voters suggesting different dup-targets... I still like it though; life would get boring without edge cases like that.

Comment: @Shog9 there couldn't be more than 5 voters, but come think of flaggers. If, say, 10 flaggers suggest 10 _different_ dupes and asker accepts, how would system handle that

Comment: Can this "stub" be visible only to the OP, @Shog9? My big worry with this is users who can't VtC posting link-only "answers" that mimic this on _other_, open, questions, because they don't know that the dupe-answers are auto-generated and think that it's just the way things are done.

Comment: @JoshCaswell how about voter/flagger who proposed a dupe? how about 10Kers, would it make sense to show it to them? I feel like not but am not sure... it seems natural for visibility of such an answer to be the same as of [accept duplicate dialog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/165773 "'That solved my problem'"), that is shown only to asker?

Comment: Yeah, those would make sense, @gnat; really just so long as it's not shown to people who might not understand that it's a special, system-generated non-answer.

Comment: okay, so we have it shown to 1) asker and voter (flagger) because they did it and system helps them see where their rep come from 2) 10Kers per their usual role - see the content hidden by the system from others and explain it when needed "- how did <this guy> get +15 from <that question>? - oh it's the hidden system post, see <screen shot>" Something like that @JoshCaswell?

Comment: @gnat Will a search that includes this question show the green circle that reflects an accepted answer? It will be odd to see the circle, click the question and not see an accepted answer. Personally, I don't think showing the stub to everyone is a problem.

Comment: @durron597 it _is_ a problem. To outsiders, it would look like a _rewarded link-only answer_ - we better abstain of widely "advertising" stuff like that (wrt green circle it's an interesting twist, really worth thinking about)

Comment: @gnat it depends on how the stub was written. It could read "##This is an auto-generated stub answer for a question that was an exact duplicate.<br/><br/>You can find the answer here: <Link>"

Comment: @durron597 I think you underestimate "creative copying" ability of inexperienced visitors. Following what is shown to them, expect them to write their answers like that: "##This is my answer for a question that was an exact duplicate.<br/><br/>You can find the answer here: <Link>" (I bet you'll see stuff like that:)

Comment: @gnat I think you're overestimating it. I VTC your comment as "primarily opinion based" ;) Also, that's only a problem if we see an awful lot of it, but not if we see it just a few times.

Comment: you just haven't seen answers I wrote when I was just starting at SO (hope I deleted most troublesome of these already)

Comment: @gnat Your sample size of 1 isn't particularly relevant ;)

Comment: make it two. I recall MSO question about some old Skeet' answer _legitimately_ getting into LQ queue. Oh, make it 3 actually, I recall voting down and flagging VLQ one of early answers of [Brian Goetz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) over here

Comment: Looks reasonable to me, @gnat, but then I'm not the one implementing it. The other (possibly easier) option would be a post with a completely different appearance than an answer, but still some kind of pseudo-checkmark.

Answer (score 4):

I totally agree with your proposal. I do have some worries that were somewhat discussed already. I want to make a post out of them because it really worries me...

From the proposal:

> We would only award the +15 rep if the asker themselves clicks the "that solved my problem!" button. If it's closed as duplicate from 5 CVs, then no rep would be assigned.

From [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260893/award-accepted-answer-reputation-for-finding-duplicates/260950#comment850756_260914):

> As far as gold badge holders, I've been thinking about this all day... I don't think it matters too much if their incentives are wrong because they already have so much rep to have gotten a gold badge (I have 13k in basically one tag and I still don't have a gold badge) they probably won't care. And there just aren't that many of them.

Based on the post [Penalty for answering help-vampire questions? Or reward closure?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299353/993547) on MSO, I am worried that gold tag badge holders are excluded from the current proposal to be rewarded. I think they should definitely be the ones that should be rewarded, for a few reasons:

- If you have a gold tag badge, you've been around quite some time. They probably know to find a lot of duplicates, so we should really encourage them to close if appropriate.
- They can be seen as *the* users capable of being the *Fastest Gun* since they can answer 90% of the questions without the need to test or fact check anything. If they aren't rewarded, they *might* not vote to close at all, and just answer.

I am also a little worried on another part of the proposal:

- The user has to take some action himself. As Shog9 mentioned, 15% of the users 'accepted' the duplicate post. That still means that 85% didn't have any participation in the closing process. Would you take the risk vote to close as a duplicate, while you can answer and be sure from some reputation? 15 reputation (as per the proposal) can be achieved by two upvotes, and that doesn't seem so much. Why not just let the closer keep his reputation if the closure wasn't disputed?

A question that came up in my mind was: does the reputation earned from this 'accepted close' feature fall in the reputation cap? If not, it could lead to a flood of close votes. If it does, one could get less motivated to vote to close, since reputation from upvotes are usually spread over days.

And can we please prevent answering a question *after* it was closed? It is possible to answer now when altering the web page a little. (Reference: [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/245360))

Comment: Surely you see the problem of giving people free rep for closing another's question? Currently there is almost no way to GIVE YOURSELF rep... One possibility is to create the stub answer when a question is dupehammered, then allow the asker to have the option of accepting it but it wouldn't be placed automatically.

Comment: One possibility to prevent abusive duplicate closure is simply to leave it in the hands of moderators and user flags and site analytic secret sauce... With very stiff penalties for repeated closures that aren't really duplicates.

Comment: I am not talking about the problem of rep farming. I am talking about leaving an important group out of the proposal. Also, there must be a way to make sure this works. Not just for 15%, for 100%. I am afraid it else might not work out well.

Comment: I know you're not talking about rep farming; you raise some very valid points here. I am simply discussing the flip side of these points.

Comment: I see no reason not to generate stub answers for *all* dup closures, including those triggered by gold badge holders. Auto-accept (and thus reputation) would need to be reserved for those cases where the asker was directly involved, but nothing stops the asker from returning later to find their question closed and a helpful answer they can accept... Indeed, this happens *today* albeit in an ad-hoc fashion.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that is a really interesting suggestion and we are keeping an eye on this one if in the future it aligns with what Product is focusing on. However, it doesn't currently play into what the team is prioritizing so I've updated the status to declined.

Comment: hmm.. shouldn't it be status-deferred then?