# Are there any studies on the techniques used to find duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-suggestions

Are there any analytics collected when a user clicks "Close as a duplicate"?

E.g.:

- how many search queries did s/he fire before pasting the exact dupe id?
- did s/he click on "Related" questions?
- how many are there dupehammer-wielding users, how active (distribution by number of dupe-closed questions per user) and how successful are they (% of "close as duplicate" approved)?

---

Feasibility:

This can be done because it's in the logs and is already allegedly exploited by the serial voting inquisition.

---

Rationale:

Discussion of this proposal - [Award accepted answer reputation for finding duplicates verified by OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260893/award-accepted-answer-reputation-for-finding-duplicates) - would benefit greatly from quantitative information.

Comment: Are you interested in actual analytics or are answers detailing how users find duplicates acceptable?

Comment: @cimmanon - analytics.

Comment: @cimmanon - sample scenarios are also welcome, but are treated as anecdotes.

Comment: Maybe or maybe not related, I have a much easier time finding the duplicate i'm looking for using the global search than i do searching through the dupe dialog.

Comment: in my experience, main "technique" to find duplicates is reading prior questions. Quoting self, "search for duplicate starts when one says to self, 'it can't be that this hasn't been asked before'..." - that _can't be_ feeling comes from vague recollection of what one have read before

Comment: @gnat - that's my own fuzzy feeling as well. Yet, this is just two data points. That's why more substantial information would be needed before the linked proposal is implemented.