# Remove reputation from closed answers

Tags: feature-request

On Stack Overflow, we have a lot of invalid questions that have a lot of upvotes, answers and selected answer. I understand that this is so because these questions are the easiest to answer, and so:

1. Incentives posting a question without search justified
2. Incentives answering a duplicated question instead of flagging it as duplicated.

I propose the following modification, to stop with this incentives: From now on, closing a question removes all reputation that the question generated.

I had this idea myself, but it is duplicated from the first answer in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions). Since it is an answer and not an question, I'm adding it here as a question just for sake of completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Just because a question is close doesn't mean that it's unsalvageable and gone for good.  The reason why we don't just delete closed questions is because there's a **chance** that they might still have value.

Deleted posts, however, do not count toward reputation.

Comment: I see, thanks, I didn't knew that deleted questions had reputation removed. In this case, I think that all duplicated questions should be deleted. Is that the case?

Comment: @fotanus duplicates aren't that big of a problem really

Comment: @fotanus: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: @SamIam that's what you claim. We have plenty of questions with more than just the suggested "some duplication" and quite frankly, Joel is wrong when he says we shouldn't worry about dupes. They make the site harder to search and water down the quality content.