# How duplicated questions currently work and how is it being used this days?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

From what I've searched I have only found topics dated of 2010 that doesn't really show much and perhaps some one will post a relevant link about this.

I've been wondering, let's say user X posts a duplicated question and it gets closed however users A, B and C had replied to it before it was closed and got some up votes and even a answer marked.

Do A, B and C keep the up vote points and also any further up votes acquired on that question?

Do close as duplicated still hold meaning, I mean most of the users will reply to it even if a duplicated question just to grab some points instead of voting to close, before it gets closed and some times it doesn't even get closed even being an exact duplicate of something else because of the current already provided answer.

---

This is a non-relevant secondary question that I would also like to know, which for instance have this question/answers [Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions?rq=1) but I don't see anything of it being deployed.

Isn't there something in place to motivate people to actually close duplicates?

Like let's say question X is a duplicate and user Y marked it, then user A, B and C backed that selection, so user Y, A, B and C get I don't know 1 to 5 points for checking the primary selection of the close as duplicate and backing that up.

Or if there were multiple selections no one gets points out of it in order to force people to actually search or verify the current selection to close it with.

It's a very simple thing that might motivate people to close duplicates and which will make people actually read the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All points are kept from questions closed as duplicates, unless they are deleted.

Awarding reputation for duplicate closures has been suggested in the very question you linked to; if you'd like to add to it, you're more than welcome to post there. Just be sure you're adding something new.

Comment: What about further points received or the selection of the answer? As for awarding reputation I see the topics but "NO ACTIONS TAKEN" by the owners or responsible team.

Comment: _All_ points are kept.

Comment: `All points are kept.` from before its closed and from after its closed so to put it simple you will still acquire points even after its closed, can you confirm that?

Comment: Yeah, that is how it works. I'm not sure what the edit to your first comment means, though?

Comment: OK thank you for the answer, would you be able to point me out to the most recent and worth contributing to question about rewarding reputation for close as duplicate? I've found a few but am not sure which one is the current golden egg question

Comment: The one you linked is probably the best one. Just make sure you've read the existing answers, as duplicate information is, well, redundant. Thank you!