# Are Stack Exchange users aiming to wide with close-as-duplicate?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I notice that many times when I ask a question, users are very keen to try and close it as a duplicate. This happens when my question is not a duplicate, it is questions similar to another but from a different angle, or a more specific or more general question, or a new idea or insight into a topic previously covered but not in a way that would directly answer that topic. Often my question will be linked to the nearest matching topic as a 'duplicate', without any real thought or sensitivity being applied.

Duplicate questions are obviously undesirable for the overall quality of the knowledge base created, I understand that.

Compared with a newsgroup, I find this anti-engagement behaviour is not very generous and at times very aggressive and you have to fight back just to try and get people to engage with the question rather than putting down the meta-question.

Why are they so keen to close you down? Do they get a bounty or something?

Comment: Because we are trying to build a *repository of good questions and their answers*. The point of duplicates are to provide *one answer* to repeated questions, even if those questions come from slightly different angles each time.

Comment: Most of all, Stack Exchange sites are **not newsgroups or forums**. You should not compare a Q&A format with those kinds of interactions.

Comment: In general, you can be confident that the community has good intentions and that you are not being targeted personally. Try spending some more time on the network to get a feel for what questions are appropriate, which ones are not, and your problem should start to resolve itself.

Comment: Well, isn't that ironic?

Comment: I'm not comparing the QA format with newsgroups, I'm comparing the attitude of the Stack Exchange community with the more generous attitude I have encountered on newsgroups. I understand there is a difference.

Comment: My other comment is, I feel that I have asked good, clear well written questions, and checked for duplicates prior to posting, but still seem to encounter this all the time.

Comment: The irony is that the duplicate of this question, is about the closest genuine duplicate I have yet encountered. In my experience, the duplicate question linked to has often been really quite different to my original.

Comment: Here is an example:
http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39072/how-to-best-respond-to-a-request-to-send-a-passport-scan-by-unsecured-email
Was initially closed as duplicate of:
http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13464/what-harm-can-be-done-with-a-copy-of-ones-passport
One is about protecting your id, the other about the consequences of not.

Comment: Ok, lets play the game. I'm editing the question...

Answer (score 14):

If you feel the duplicate doesn't answer your question, then edit your question and clearly explain how it is different from the duplicate.

Your edit will automatically put your question in a re-open queue, and if enough people agree with you that your question is indeed a different one, it will be re-opened.

It really is as simple as that.

Answer (score 10):

> Why are they so keen to close you down? Do they get a bounty or something?

They are trying to keep the site clean. **There is no reputation or badge directly attached to closing duplicates.** In some cases when someone closes a question as a duplicate of another question they answered, some people will accuse the close-voter of a conflict of interest but isn't the close-voter more likely to remember the question they answered way back when than some other question they happened to run into at some point?

> Often my question will be linked to the nearest matching one as a 'duplicate', without any real thought or sensitivity being applied.

That's quite the assumption you're making there. Did it occur to you that perhaps:

- People who are reading your question are not understanding it the way you do because it is not clearly written?
- Maybe *you* do not see how your question is a duplicate but it does not mean that it isn't?

The thing to do when your question is marked as duplicate is to **take time to explain what it is you *do* know and how your question actually differs from the other**. If you cannot do this, that's your sign that your question is a duplicate. If you do it well, your question will be reopened. If your explanation is faulty, you may get a comment explaining your error, and why your question *is*, in fact, a duplicate.

Comment: Related: [Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37466/259693)

Comment: As I say, I think my questions were not duplicates, but those trying to close them did not really make much effort in reading the question and comparing it with the so-called duplicate. This leads to me wasting effort on dealing with the meta-question, which would not be so bad if it did not happen all the time.

Answer (score 10):

To make a few points that the other answers haven't yet:

> Duplicate questions are obviously undesirable for the overall quality of the knowledge base created, I understand that.

Quite the contrary, in fact. We discourage *deleting* duplicates (while typically closing is a path to deletion) because they act as "signposts." They help other users find the questions they're looking for. If you used the search terms mentioned in your question and were unable to find the duplicate target, perhaps someone later might use the same search terms and wind up finding the better question.

> Compared with a newsgroup,

If you prefer newsgroups, then by all means do go ahead and use newsgroups. Stack Exchange question and answer sites fill a very, very different niche.

> I find this anti-engagement behaviour is not very generous and at times very aggressive and you have to fight back just to try and get people to engage with the question rather than putting down the meta-question.

Perhaps it's the *question* at fault here, and not the other people? If your question is marked as a duplicate, it's probably for a good reason, and 95% of the time, you'll find your answer at the linked duplicate. (If the question really *isn't* a duplicate, you can get it reopened as explained in @Yannis's answer.)

> Why are they so keen to close you down?

"close you down"? Users who find duplicates for you are helping both you (by directing you to an answer to your question) and the general quality of the site's content as a whole (by helping future visitors do the same). Remember, the ultimate goal of Stack Exchange is not to help one specific user, but to build a repository of high-quality Q&A to help many future visitors, too.

Comment: And afterall they're not closing *"you"* down but *your question*, which is quite a difference that's sometimes overlooked.