# 'Total rep awarded from bounties' mark overlays controls on short answers for iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, ios-app

The 'Total rep awarded from bounties' mark for answers covers the controls on short answers on the iOS app.

[image: Bounty box on a short answer]

This seems to be because the bounty box is positioned based on the vote buttons (to allow room for a possible accept mark) rather than filling an appropriately small space.

Another related bug is that these misaligned bounty boxes disappear when scrolled off the top of the screen. When you scroll back up, they are gone. On the contrary, when you scroll it off the bottom of the screen and back, it reappears.

When scrolled off the top:
[image: bounty box after being scrolled off the top]

When scrolled off the bottom: 
[image: bou to box scrolled off the bottom]

To reproduce, visit a short answer (<8 lines or so) on the iOS app which has been awarded bounties, such as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37478/285368). Continue scrolling past it till it goes off the screen, then scroll back up. Then repeat in reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.3.5.

The problem was that the answer section was assuming a minimum height of 150 would be enough for anything.  (Looking at git, this was almost certainly caused by my own laziness during a refactor.)

Now the minimum height will be calculated based on the actual contents of the left hand side *and* for good measure I'm removing the gap between the bounty and the score when answer is not accepted and you aren't the question owner.  As a side note, this was the first time I really wished I had access to the iOS9-only UIStackView.

[image: Screenshot showing the bounty contained within the answer and closer to the down vote button because the question is not accepted.]